# Moving Codeigniter to another programmers computer

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I would like to move my current codeigniter Project Which works fine in my laptop as well as my desktop but when i try to move  codeigniter project to other system default controller   is loading but  when i try to access other pages it is not working i get error Not found the rquested url was not found on this server

both system has windows 10 and wamp

please help me to solve my problem

Comment: Please see .htaccess is copied to another pc or not ?

Comment: How do you move CI to another machine ?

Comment: @rakesh yes i copied .htaccess

Comment: @Alok I Moved My project Folder to Usb Then I Moved From Usb To Other System

Comment: Checked AllowOverride is set to all in Apache-config?

Comment: Is rewrite_mod enabled ?

Comment: @ rakesh it worked man

Comment: @jannej  really appreciate for spending time for me

Comment: Also make sure you follow the latest codeigniter file and class style guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Ok i got it I will do like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first to copy your project folder than to move window 10 wamp inside the paste the project.
2. open your phpmyadmin and create a same database name than to import database
3. open a .htaccess file and paste below code.

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [L]
4. if any case your project not run than you facing some issue so please check first of all  rewrite_mod enabled or disable. if rewrite_mod disable so please enable it.

Comment: problem resolved i did as rakesh said i enabled rewrite_mod on wamp